# Is there a way to shorten this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Name,  
REPLACE(RTRIM((
                SELECT CAST(Score AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT Name, Score
                    FROM table
                    WHERE 
                    ---CONDITIONS---
                    ) AS InnerTable             
                WHERE (InnerTable.Name = OuterTable.Name) FOR XML PATH (''))),' ',', ') AS Scores
FROM table AS OuterTable
WHERE 
---CONDITIONS---
GROUP BY Name;
```

As it can be seen, I am using the same set of conditions to derive the `InnerTable` and `OuterTable`. Is there a way to shorten this query? I am asking this because, sometime back, I saw a keyword `USING` in MySQL that simplified my life using which you can specify a query once and then use its alias for the rest of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at creating a Common Table Expression (CTE).  That is your best bet for aliasing a select.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how much shoerter it will make your query though it does prevent you from defining the where conditions twice.  see below:

```
with temp as
(
   SELECT Name, Score
   FROM table
   WHERE whatever = 'whatever'
)

SELECT Name,  
REPLACE(RTRIM((
                SELECT CAST(Score AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT Name, Score
                    FROM temp                    ) AS InnerTable             
                WHERE (InnerTable.Name = OuterTable.Name) FOR XML PATH (''))),' ',', ') AS Scores
FROM temp AS OuterTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. I think this is what I need. It makes my query more readable. I'll accept this as an answer when the timer expires. :)